# How to preserve pandas dataframe columns using to_sql

Tags: pandas, sqlite

I want to store some data from dataframes into an sqlite database. I am doing the following:

first create a database:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
```

then add table from dataframe `df` to database:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, conn,if_exists='append')
```

then querying the table from the database:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
rows = cur.fetchall()
df2=pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

`df2` does not have the original common names but has been reindex to 0, 1,2,3 etc.

How can I preserve the columns of the original dataframe?

Thank you

Comment: can you post an output of `print(df.columns.tolist())` __before__ you write to SQLite?

Comment: it's a list of strings, but some of them contain spaces. could that create the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
df2 = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name", conn)
```

some color:

your table is fine, it has the columns, you fetch a list of tuple of values using cur.fetchall() it does not have any info for columns name so pandas just use numbers.

`read_sql()` check for column names and does it for you